# How to retrieve current tag name in awesome wm?

Tags: awesome-wm

I am looking to replace the tag list in awesome WM with a simple text box that only displays the name of the current tag. I have tried to create a textbox that contains the following code:

```
mytagbox = widget({ type = "textbox" })
mytagbox.text = awful.tag.selected(s).getproperty("name")
```

But this does not work and reverts awesome to its default config. What is the correct code I need to put in to make this possible? I'm also using Shifty. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were close to the correct way:

```
screen[1]:connect_signal("tag::history::update", function()
       mytagbox.text = awful.tag.selected(1).name
end)

-- Or add_signal on awesome < 3.5
```

So `mytagbox.text` will be changing on each tags switching.

Comment: Thanks, I have put that code in my rc.lua and it half works - it displays the name of the first tag opened on login, but when I change tags after that, it doesn't update. I have written a function that returns `tagname`, but where should I make a call to that function in rc.lua so that it changes with the tags? Cheers

Comment: You should just put `mytagbox.text = awful.tag.selected(1).name` into `tag::history::update` signal of screen[1]. I've updated example in my answer above.

Comment: For awesome 3.5 you should use "connect_signal" instead of add_signal, could you update your answer because this doesn't work anymore with awesome 3.5 and it doesn't generate any error.(it tooks me some time to figure out why this didn't work).

Comment: Awesome is now in its version 4.0, is this obsolete ?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to change filter function on taglist

```
mytaglist[s] = awful.widget.taglist(s, function(t, args) return t.selected end, mytaglist.buttons)
```